# javascript alert() not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to add some data in the database , after insertion i want an alert but it doesn't working besides that header() function is working.

```
<?php
        include("connection.php");  
        if(isset($_POST['submit_bank']))
        {
            $b_date=$_POST['bank_date'];
            $b_type=$_POST['bank_type'];
            $b_name=$_POST['bank_name'];
            $b_bname=$_POST['bank_bname'];
            $b_amount=$_POST['bank_amount'];

            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO banking_info(b_date,b_type,b_name,b_branch,b_amount) 
                VALUES('$b_date','$b_type','$b_name','$b_bname','$b_amount')");
            if ($result!=0)
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Addition Successfull !!');</script>";
                header("Location: banking.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Addition Failed !!');</script>";
                header("Location: banking.php");
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy: you have Location header:

```
 echo "<script>alert('Addition Successfull !!');</script>";
 header("Location: banking.php");
```

When you send Location header to user, he/she will get redirected and script won't be interpreted!

P.S: As @Quentin said, **mysql_** functions are deprecated, they're old and no longer maintained. Use **mysqli**  or **PDO**.

P.S 2: You send content before header, so assume you're using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: @Sébastien Sorry, Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You header away right after the echo, but that should give an error (you can not `header()` if output (like echo) has been put on the screen).

I asume you use something like `ob_start()`
**I suggest the following method:**

```
header("Location: banking.php?alert=Addition%20Successfull%20!!");
```

and check in balking.php for `isset($_GET['alert'])`, if so, echo it, if not, dont do anything

Comment: but header is working.. i just tried your method and itssssssssssssssssssssss working...thank you

Comment: Please mark as solution for other people who read this topic :)

Comment: actually i need to know how to mark an answer as a solution.

Comment: Nexto my post is a number, under that number you'll see a outlined mark, click that :)

Answer (score 0):

header("Location: banking.php"); redirect you before javascript run
use `<script>window.location.replace("http://mydomain.com/banking.php");</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if ($result!=0)
        {
            echo "<script>
                     alert('Addition Successfull !!');
                     window.location.replace('banking.php');
                  </script>";
            //header("Location: banking.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>
                     alert('Addition Failed !!');
                     window.location.replace('banking.php');
                  </script>";
            //***strong text***header("Location: banking.php");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo "<script>alert('Addition Failed !!');window.location='index.php';</script>";exit;
```

it terminates running php and executes javascript